# ROS2 access to privileged processes by command file

Tags: ros2, robot-upstart

I am running my ROS2 processes as privileged processes as they need access to hardware.

Like: `seetpriv --reuid root ros2 launch ...`

The reason I do this is to be able to start these independent ros processes at bootup using ros-humble-upstart package.

While everything works well, from a shell on the RaspberryPI that all this is connected to I can not reach topics, with my unprivileged user.

This hadn't been a problem in ROS1. Is there a way to override this security feature, or maybe a workaround to run 'ros2 ..' with setuuid=0 on the robot?

Meanwhile across hosts, topics are completely accessible.

Best regards,
C.A.